# Freeze scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I create a game using javascript. The code is placed at the bottom of the page. Visualize it as if the game is below a footer. The game starts when the user selects the start game button. The mechanics of the game are controlled by the arrow key. Arrow keys are used to move up, right, and left down. The problem is when I press the up or down key, the page scrolls too. How to stop this? I want the page not to scroll when the game is active. I am attaching the code of the game I create. It is a snake game.There's CSS too, but I'm not attaching it as I don't think its relevant

```
 <div id="app" class="app">
          <div class="start-screen">
            <h2> </h2>
      
            <div class="options">
              <h3>Choose Difficulty</h3>
              <p class="end-score"></p>
              <button data-difficulty="100" class="active">Easy</button>
              <button data-difficulty="75">Medium</button>
              <button data-difficulty="50">Hard</button>
            </div>
      
            <button class="play-btn">Play</button>
          </div>
      
          <canvas id="board"></canvas>
      
          <div class="score">0</div>
        </div>

<script>
class SnakeGame {
  constructor() {
    this.$app = document.querySelector('#app');
    this.$canvas = this.$app.querySelector('canvas');
    this.ctx = this.$canvas.getContext('2d');
    this.$startScreen = this.$app.querySelector('.start-screen');
    this.$score = this.$app.querySelector('.score');

    this.settings = {
      canvas: {
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        background: 'white',
        border: 'black'
      },
      snake: {
        size: 20,
        background: '#73854A',
        border: '#000'
      }
    };

    this.game = {
      // "direction" (set in setUpGame())
      // "nextDirection" (set in setUpGame())
      // "score" (set in setUpGame())
      speed: 100,
      keyCodes: {
        38: 'up',
        40: 'down',
        39: 'right',
        37: 'left'
      }  
    }

    this.soundEffects = {
      score: new Audio('./sounds/score.mp3'),
      gameOver: new Audio('./sounds/game-over.mp3')
    };

    this.setUpGame();
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    // Choose difficulty
    // Rather than using "this.$startScreen.querySelectorAll('button')" and looping over the node list
    // and attaching seperate event listeners on each item, it's more efficient to just listen in on the container and run a check at runtime
    this.$startScreen.querySelector('.options').addEventListener('click', event => {
      this.chooseDifficulty(event.target.dataset.difficulty);
    });

    // Play
    this.$startScreen.querySelector('.play-btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.startGame();
    });
  }

  chooseDifficulty(difficulty) {
    if(difficulty) {
      this.game.speed = difficulty;
      this.$startScreen.querySelectorAll('.options button').forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('active'));
      event.target.classList.add('active');
    }
  }

  setUpGame() {
    // The snake starts off with 5 pieces
    // Each piece is 30x30 pixels
    // Each following piece must be n times as far from the first piece
    const x = 300;
    const y = 300;

    this.snake = [
      { x: x, y: y },
      { x: x - this.settings.snake.size, y: y },
      { x: x - (this.settings.snake.size * 2), y: y },
      { x: x - (this.settings.snake.size * 3), y: y },
      { x: x - (this.settings.snake.size * 4), y: y }
    ];

    this.food = {
      active: false,
      background: '#EC5E0B',
      border: '#73AA24',
      coordinates: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0  
      }
    };

    this.game.score = 0;
    this.game.direction = 'right';
    this.game.nextDirection = 'right';
  }

  startGame() {
    // Stop the game over sound effect if a new game was restarted quickly before it could end
    this.soundEffects.gameOver.pause();
    this.soundEffects.gameOver.currentTime = 0;

    // Reset a few things from the prior game
    this.$app.classList.add('game-in-progress');
    this.$app.classList.remove('game-over');
    this.$score.innerText = 0;

    this.generateSnake();

    this.startGameInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if(!this.detectCollision()) {
        this.generateSnake();
      } else {
        this.endGame();
      }
    }, this.game.speed);

    // Change direction
    document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
      this.changeDirection(event.keyCode);
    });
  }

  changeDirection(keyCode) {
    const validKeyPress = Object.keys(this.game.keyCodes).includes(keyCode.toString()); // Only allow (up|down|left|right)

    if(validKeyPress && this.validateDirectionChange(this.game.keyCodes[keyCode], this.game.direction)) {
      this.game.nextDirection = this.game.keyCodes[keyCode];
    }
  }

  // When already moving in one direction snake shouldn't be allowed to move in the opposite direction
  validateDirectionChange(keyPress, currentDirection) {
    return (keyPress === 'left' && currentDirection !== 'right') || 
      (keyPress === 'right' && currentDirection !== 'left') ||
      (keyPress === 'up' && currentDirection !== 'down') ||
      (keyPress === 'down' && currentDirection !== 'up');
  }

  resetCanvas() {
    // Full screen size
    this.$canvas.width = this.settings.canvas.width;
    this.$canvas.height = this.settings.canvas.height;
    this.$canvas.style.border = `3px solid ${this.settings.canvas.border}`;

    // Background
    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.settings.canvas.background;
    this.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, this.$canvas.width, this.$canvas.height);
  }

  generateSnake() {
    let coordinate;

    switch(this.game.direction) {
      case 'right':
        coordinate = {
          x: this.snake[0].x + this.settings.snake.size,
          y: this.snake[0].y
        };
      break;
      case 'up':
        coordinate = {
          x: this.snake[0].x,
          y: this.snake[0].y - this.settings.snake.size
        };
      break;
      case 'left':
        coordinate = {
          x: this.snake[0].x - this.settings.snake.size,
          y: this.snake[0].y
        };
      break;
      case 'down':
        coordinate = {
          x: this.snake[0].x,
          y: this.snake[0].y + this.settings.snake.size
        };
    }

    // The snake moves by adding a piece to the beginning "this.snake.unshift(coordinate)" and removing the last piece "this.snake.pop()"
    // Except when it eats the food in which case there is no need to remove a piece and the added piece will make it grow
    this.snake.unshift(coordinate);
    this.resetCanvas();

    const ateFood = this.snake[0].x === this.food.coordinates.x && this.snake[0].y === this.food.coordinates.y;

    if(ateFood) {
      this.food.active = false;
      this.game.score += 10;
      this.$score.innerText = this.game.score;
      this.soundEffects.score.play();
    } else {
      this.snake.pop();
    }

    this.generateFood();
    this.drawSnake();
  }

  drawSnake() {
    const size = this.settings.snake.size;

    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.settings.snake.background;
    this.ctx.strokestyle = this.settings.snake.border;

    // Draw each piece
    this.snake.forEach(coordinate => {
      this.ctx.fillRect(coordinate.x, coordinate.y, size, size);
      this.ctx.strokeRect(coordinate.x, coordinate.y, size, size);
    });

    this.game.direction = this.game.nextDirection;
  }

  generateFood() {
    // If there is uneaten food on the canvas there's no need to regenerate it
    if(this.food.active) {
      this.drawFood(this.food.coordinates.x, this.food.coordinates.y);
      return;
    }

    const gridSize = this.settings.snake.size;
    const xMax = this.settings.canvas.width - gridSize;
    const yMax = this.settings.canvas.height - gridSize;

    const x = Math.round((Math.random() * xMax) / gridSize) * gridSize;
    const y = Math.round((Math.random() * yMax) / gridSize) * gridSize;

    // Make sure the generated coordinates do not conflict with the snake's present location
    // If so recall this method recursively to try again
    this.snake.forEach(coordinate => {
      const foodSnakeConflict = coordinate.x == x && coordinate.y == y;

      if(foodSnakeConflict) {
        this.generateFood();
      } else {
        this.drawFood(x, y);
      }
    });
  }

  drawFood(x, y) {
    const size = this.settings.snake.size;

    this.ctx.fillStyle = this.food.background;
    this.ctx.strokestyle = this.food.border;

    this.ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size);
    this.ctx.strokeRect(x, y, size, size);

    this.food.active = true;
    this.food.coordinates.x = x;
    this.food.coordinates.y = y;
  }

  detectCollision() {
    // Self collison
    // It's impossible for the first 3 pieces of the snake to self collide so the loop starts at 4
    for(let i = 4; i < this.snake.length; i++) {
      const selfCollison = this.snake[i].x === this.snake[0].x && this.snake[i].y === this.snake[0].y;

      if(selfCollison) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    // Wall collison
    const leftCollison = this.snake[0].x < 0;
    const topCollison = this.snake[0].y < 0;
    const rightCollison = this.snake[0].x > this.$canvas.width - this.settings.snake.size;
    const bottomCollison = this.snake[0].y > this.$canvas.height - this.settings.snake.size;

    return leftCollison || topCollison || rightCollison || bottomCollison;
  }

  endGame() {
    this.soundEffects.gameOver.play();

    clearInterval(this.startGameInterval);

    this.$app.classList.remove('game-in-progress');
    this.$app.classList.add('game-over');
    this.$startScreen.querySelector('.options h3').innerText = 'Game Over';
    this.$startScreen.querySelector('.options .end-score').innerText = `Score: ${this.game.score}`;

    this.setUpGame();
  }
}

const snakeGame = new SnakeGame();
</script>
```

Stop the page from moving up and down when the game is active

Answer (score 0):

You just need to prevent the default behaviour of these keys:

```
// Change direction
document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
  event.preventDefault(); // add this line
  this.changeDirection(event.keyCode);
});
```

Note that this isn't a very good idea to do it that way, as it will prevent the default behaviour of *all* keypresses *anywhere* on your page. Most notably, F5 will never refresh the browser, and if you have other elements like buttons, links, etc, the standard keypresses to activate those will stop working (turning these off is a particular problem if you want your site to be accessible to those with disabilities).

You'd be better off checking the keyCode first and only preventing default if it corresponds to one of the arrow keys - which isn't so easy to do with your code as it stands but I'd encourage you to rewrite it that way.

Even doing that presents a problem to those who are not able to use a mouse, as (depending on the position of your game interface on the screen and its size) they may still need to scroll down and will be prevented from doing this by this `preventDefault` behaviour. But well that's what you asked for, and I've given you the solution - but with this important caveat.